# Forçar saída do laço while em switch C

Tags: c, while, switch

Galera, eu fiz um menu em linguagem C, porem preciso que quando o usuário digite a opção 4, ele saia do laço de repetição do/while, alguém pode me ajudar. Mais uma vez obrigado a todos pela participação.

```
int opcao;

do
{
    menu();
    printf("\n");
    printf("Opção selecionada: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &opcao);

    switch (opcao)
    {
        case 1: adicionar();
            break;
        case 2: modificar();
            break;
        case 3: relatorio();
            break;
        case 4: Sair;
    }
} while ((opcao >= 1) && (opcao <=4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o que deseja é:

```
int opcao;
do {
    menu();
    printf("\nOpção selecionada: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &opcao);
    switch (opcao) {
        case 1: 
            adicionar();
            break;
        case 2: 
            modificar();
            break;
        case 3: 
            relatorio();
            break;
        case 4: 
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nOpção inválida");
    }
} while (opcao != 4);
```

Comment: Top, era exatamente isso que eu queria fazer muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu código estiver dentro de uma função, você poderia usar `return` para sair, veja só:

```
void foobar(void) {
    int opcao;

    while(1) {
        menu();
        printf("\n");
        printf("Opção selecionada: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &opcao);

        switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                adicionar();
                break;
            case 2:
                modificar();
                break;
            case 3:
                relatorio();
                break;
            case 4:
                return;
            default:
                printf("\nOpção inválida");
        }
    }
}
```